# Part of code into variable

Tags: php

how can I incorporate the code in php in "My Code" part?

```
$out.= '<li class="portfolio_item overlayed_animated_highlight portfolio_item_4' . $slugs . '">
            <div class="overlayed">
                ' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '
                <div class="overlay">
                    <p>
                        <a href="'.get_permalink().'"><i class="icon-share"></i></a>
                        <a href="'.$thumbnail_src.'" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="portfolio"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            /** my code **/
            <h4><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>
            <span>' . get_the_date() . ' // ' . $in_category . '</span>
        </li>';
```

/** my code**/

```
<?php if( get_field('field_name') ): ?>
<div><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></p></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should read these: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
$out .= '<li class="portfolio_item overlayed_animated_highlight portfolio_item_4' . $slugs . '">
            <div class="overlayed">
                ' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '
                <div class="overlay">
                    <p>
                        <a href="'.get_permalink().'"><i class="icon-share"></i></a>
                        <a href="'.$thumbnail_src.'" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="portfolio"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>';

if( get_field('field_name') ) {
    $out .= '<div><p>' . the_field('field_name') . '</p></div>';
}

$out .= '<h4><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>
            <span>' . get_the_date() . ' // ' . $in_category . '</span>
        </li>';
```

Comment: So much more messy than using a ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ternary operator.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) Try this:

```
$out.= '<li class="portfolio_item overlayed_animated_highlight portfolio_item_4' . $slugs . '">
        <div class="overlayed">
            ' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '
            <div class="overlay">
                <p>
                    <a href="'.get_permalink().'"><i class="icon-share"></i></a>
                    <a href="'.$thumbnail_src.'" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="portfolio"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        '.(get_field('field_name') ? '<div>'.the_field('field_name').'</div>' : '').'
        <h4><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>
        <span>' . get_the_date() . ' // ' . $in_category . '</span>
    </li>';
```